# Por quê o output dos meus objetos se quebram (em diferentes linhas) caso haja mais de 60 caracteres?

Tags: javascript, input-output

Minha questão é bem simples: por quê se meu objeto tiver mais de 60 caracteres, no total, ele imprime em diferentes linhas cada chave e valor, enquanto caso tenha menos de 60 tudo é impresso em uma linha só? É algum tipo de convenção?

Fiz uma pesquisa para saber se era convenção e o máximo que consegui de resposta não foi a respeito específico de programação, mas de readability em geral, porém a maioria falava de 80 caracteres.

Procurei nos documentations mas não achei nada sobre também. Não tenho conhecimento suficiente para fazer o teste em Python, já que não sei lidar com objetos ainda da mesma forma que JS.

Por exemplo:

```js
let biblioteca = [
    { titulo: 'Os Miseráveis', autor: 'Victor Hugo', bibliotecaID: 4264 },
];
```

Retorna, ao chamar `console.log(biblioteca)`:

```js
[
  { titulo: 'Os Miseráveis', autor: 'Victor Hugo', bibliotecaID: 4264 }
]
```

Porém, se eu alterar o título de **Os Miseráveis** para **Les Miserábles**, passando assim de 60 caracteres na linha do objeto, o output é o seguinte:

```js
[
  {
    titulo: 'Les Misérables',
    autor: 'Victor Hugo',
    bibliotecaID: 4264
  }
]
```

Fiz o teste no VSCode com o Code Runner e também tentei no Terminal para ver se não era uma característica do VSCode, mas nos dois o resultado foi o mesmo. Não vejo nenhum problema nisso, embora o segundo seja bem mais legível, mas fiquei curioso: há alguma explicação/leitura a respeito disso?

Obrigado!

Comment: [Acabei de testar o código](https://imgur.com/a/dt9BBJn) não há nada demais.

Comment: [Teste do Código](https://i.imgur.com/tCQs7Bn.png). Interessante, eu testei agora no repl.it mas recebo a mesma resposta de antes.